# Is there a modern way to enclose a int to a range?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

*I will clarify. I want to create a int variable in range [min,max] with next
properties:*

1. It must support  '+'(plus) and '-'(minus) operations with int.
2. Any value more than max should loop around to [min + remainder.
3. Any value less than min should loop around to max - remainder].

## **Examples:**

```
int a in range (2,7);
a = 3;
a = a + 3; // a is 6 now
a = a + 1; // a is 7 now
a = a + 1; // a is greater than 7 so we loop to 2 a = 2
a = a - 3; // shoul be 2 - 3 = -1 but insted will be 5 (2 - 1 -> 7 - 2 -> 5)
```

I know i can write upper bound with mod (aka `%` operator). But i think the code will be hard to read.

Or using if statement. But then the performance will drop.

So it there some modern way to do it? Some `std::` solution? Or cool syntaxis?

Answer (score 1):

```
template<class T, T min, T max>
struct bounded_value {
  static_assert(min <= max);
private:
  T t;
public:
  explicit operator T() const& { return t; }
  explicit operator T() && { return std::move(t); }

  inline static constexpr T delta = max-min;

  bounded_value& operator+=( bounded_value const& o ) & {
    t += o.t;
    if (t >= max)
      t -= delta;
    else if (t < min)
      t += delta;
    return *this;
  }
  bounded_value& operator-=( bounded_value const& o ) & {
    t -= o.t;
    if (t >= max)
      t -= delta;
    else if (t < min)
      t += delta;
    return *this;
  }
  static T bound( T in ) {
    if (in > max)
    {
      std::size_t count = (max-in)/delta;
      in -= delta * count;
    }
    else if (in <= min)
    {
      std::size_t count = (min-in)/delta;
      in += delta * count;
    }
    return in;
  }
  bounded_value& operator*=( bounded_value const& o ) & {
    t = bound(t * o.t);
    return *this;
  }
  bounded_value& operator/=( bounded_value const& o ) & {
    t = bound(t / o.t);
    return *this;
  }

  friend bounded_value operator+(bounded_value lhs, bounded_value const& rhs)
  {
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
  }
  friend bounded_value operator-(bounded_value lhs, bounded_value const& rhs)
  {
    lhs -= rhs;
    return lhs;
  }
  friend bounded_value operator*(bounded_value lhs, bounded_value const& rhs)
  {
    lhs *= rhs;
    return lhs;
  }
  friend bounded_value operator/(bounded_value lhs, bounded_value const& rhs)
  {
    lhs /= rhs;
    return lhs;
  }

  bounded_value& operator++(){ *this += 1; return *this; }
  bounded_value operator++(int){ auto tmp = *this; ++*this; return tmp;}
  bounded_value& operator--(){ *this -= 1; return *this; }
  bounded_value operator--(int){ auto tmp = *this; ++*this; return tmp;}

  auto operator<=>(bounded_value const&) const =default;
  bool operator==(bounded_value const&) const =default;

  bounded_value( T in ):t( bound(std::move(in)) ) {}
  bounded_value():t(min) {}
  ~bounded_value()=default;
  bounded_value( bounded_value const& )=default;
  bounded_value( bounded_value && )=default;
  bounded_value& operator=( bounded_value const& )=default;
  bounded_value& operator=( bounded_value && )=default;
};
```

that is a quick one.

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/W77o5Gava).

I should probably add `std::ptrdiff_t` overloads on `+` and `-`, to support `bounded_value<Foo*, globalbuf+10, globalbuf+100>`.

Note that this assumes that operations on the bounded values do not over/under flow the underlying `T`.

When doing `+` and `-` up to two check are made, and one subtraction/addition, to keep it within bounds; no division.  When doing `*` and `/`, up to two checks, a division, a multiplication, and an addition/subtraction is done.

Comment: I believe this will work even on "overflow" for integer data types with size less than `int` because of integer promotion during the arithmetic operations.